# nesC: converting float number to integer

Tags: c, floating-point-conversion, nesc

I want to make xor of an `uint16` with a floating point number like the following:

```
uint16_t a=20000;
double r,x,xo;
r=3.8;
xo=.1;
x=(int) r*xo*(1-xo);
c=a^x;
```

When I run the test the following error occurs:

```
invalid operand to binary ^
```

How can I convert `x` to an integer value with 16 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `x` is still a double value. The cast in

```
x=(int) r*xo*(1-xo);
```

truncates the number, but it's still a double number.

To do what you want you need to declare `x`  as `int` or cast right before xor:

```
c=a^((int)x);
```

Answer (score 0):

nesC is an extension of C, so you can convert a floating point number to an integer just like you would do it in C, with a cast.
For example:

```
(int)(x+0.5)
```

Note that this has limitations, see more details here: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/round.html